# Action button working only 1 time with {daff} html output in R {shiny}

Tags: r, shiny

The code below is built in two parts for editing excel file in `{shiny}` with the excellent `{dataEditr}` package

- First action is to write in new excel and click button to save
- Second part, a modal dialog is shown for validating changes

But when I validate or not the changes, I can no more open the modal dialog when save button is clicked.

Plus, when I show only text or table in the modal dialog, all work fine.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(daff)
library(dplyr)
library(DataEditR)

df1 = iris %>% slice(1:10) %>% select(-Species)
df2 = iris %>% slice(1:12)

# Define UI
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "First data",
        status = "success",
        width = 6,
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        dataEditUI(id = "old_data")
      ),
      box(
        title = "New data",
        status = "primary",
        width = 6,
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        dataEditUI(id = "new_data"),
        br(),
        actionButton("save", "Save!")
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server
server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_old = dataEditServer(
    "old_data",
    data = df1, 
    col_readonly = names(df1),
    col_names = FALSE,
    col_options = TRUE,
    row_edit = FALSE
  )
  
  data_new = dataEditServer(
    "new_data",
    data = df2, 
    col_names = FALSE,
    col_options = TRUE,
    row_edit = FALSE
  ) 
  
  diff_data = reactive({
    daff::render_diff(
      daff::diff_data(
        data_old(),
        data_new()
      ), view = FALSE
    )
  })
  
  output$compare_df = renderUI({
    HTML(
      diff_data()
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(
    input$save, {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          span(
            "Check modification before validation!",
            style = "color: red; font-size: 130%;"
          ),
          br(),
          br(),
          uiOutput("compare_df"),
          footer = tagList(
            modalButton("Cancel"),
            actionButton("ok", "OK")
          ),
          easyClose = TRUE,
          size = "l"
        )
      )
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    input$ok, {
      print(data_new())
      removeModal()
    }
  )
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`daff::render_diff` by default renders a complete HTML document. This causes JS errors when the modal is first displayed (i.e. the first time "Save!" is clicked). You can see this by changing the `renderUI`. The modal will show the literal HTML code instead of trying to render it

```
  output$compare_df = renderUI({
    div(# HTML(
      diff_data()
    )
  })
```

The fix is to use the `fragment` argument which will produce only the HTML table, which `renderUI` will know how to handle

```
  diff_data = reactive({
    daff::render_diff(
      daff::diff_data(
        data_old(),
        data_new()
      ), 
      view = FALSE,
      fragment = TRUE
    )
  })
```

The downside of this is the complete HTML document contains CSS in it that is not included with just the fragment. You are then responsible for styling the resulting table.